# Как использовать массив в качестве freight key?

Tags: sql, postgresql

Имеется две таблицы. Надо связать их при помощи foreign key, но проблема в том, что элемент из таблицы B может ссылаться на несколько элементов таблицы A, но при использовании массива даёт ошибку.
Хотелось узнать, как можно решить данную проблему и как правильно использовать REFERENCES если у нас не один элемент, а массив.

```
CREATE TABLE a
(
    id       BIGSERIAL   PRIMARY KEY,
    name     TEXT        NOT NULL,
    created  TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);

CREATE TABLE b 
(
    id       BIGSERIAL   PRIMARY KEY,
    name     TEXT        NOT NULL,
    b_id     BIGINT[]    NOT NULL REFERENCES courses,
    active   BOOLEAN     NOT NULL DEFAULT TRUE,
    created  TIMESTAMP   NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP
);
```

Comment: Связь типа много-ко-много требует создания промежуточной связующей таблицы.

Comment: "Создание промежуточной связующей таблицы"-хммм... Надо поискать, но если вы можете написать как это сделать, то буду признателен)

Comment: Создание таблицу C в которой два F.K. на таблицу A и B, и при необходимости вытащить все нужные данные из A по средством С? Гениально!